# how can I display the name of a country the user has chosen an another linked page in jsp

Tags: html, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

So in my program the user will select a country they want to go to, once they click submit it will take them to another page with the name of the country they chose. how will I do this im a bit confused can I please get help
thanks.

```
  <h2>Travel the world</h2>

   <p>choose a country you'd like to go</p>


    <form:form method = "POST"  action="/Country/"  model attribute = "model"> 

    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
      <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
     </div>
    <a id="ToProductsBtn" href="/Country/" class="btn btn-default">lets go</a>
      <input  type=submit id="ToProductsBtn" href="/Country/" class="btn btn-default" value ="lets go" class="btn btn-default">

   </form:form>
  <script>

       </form:form>
     <script>
        function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

         var currentFocus;

        inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            var a, b, i, val = this.value;

          closeAllLists();
           if (!val) { return false;}
          currentFocus = -1;

           a = document.createElement("DIV");
          a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
           a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

            this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

               if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {

                 b = document.createElement("DIV");

              b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
             b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);

              b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

             b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

                     inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")   [0].value;

            closeAllLists();
        });
       a.appendChild(b);
        }
          }
       });

        inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            var x = document.getElementById(this.id +       "autocomplete-list");
           if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
          if (e.keyCode == 40) {

             currentFocus++;

              addActive(x);
           } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
              currentFocus--;

              addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

              e.preventDefault();
             if (currentFocus > -1) {

               if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
             }
            }
          });
        function addActive(x) {

          if (!x) return false;

          removeActive(x);
          if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
         if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);

         x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
           }
       function removeActive(x) {

         for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
          }
        }
       function closeAllLists(elmnt) {

         var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
          for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
             x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
            }
          }
        }

      document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
           closeAllLists(e.target);
         });
       }


          var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint  Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];


         autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
         </script>

    </body>
     </html>


     </select>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is the jsp it gets linked to however in this JSP I want the program to display the name of the country chosen.

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;     charset=UTF-8"
      pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
   </head>
     <h1>${name}</h1>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

here are my controller
 package travel.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

```
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;
 import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

 import travel.domain.Order;


 @Controller

 public class Place {
@RequestMapping(value="/addcountry")

public String place(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="PLACE") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "form/Place";}

@RequestMapping (value="/Country")
public String Country(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false,   defaultValue="myCountry") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "form/Country";}
```